# Cannot connect to MySQL Server running inside WSL2

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, wsl-2

I have a problems connecting to a MySQL database that is running in WSL2 via MySQL Workbench. I tried different methods that i found on StackOverflow, but none of them helped.

What did i try:

1. Created new user and granted access to a Database.
2. Changed authentication method to `mysql_native_password`
3. Tried hostname: `127.0.0.1` and `localhost`
4. Disabled Firewall on Windows 10

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 with MySQL 8.0.25 in WSL2

[image]

Comment: The dialogue shows you're establishing a connection, otherwise the server would not be telling you that the username and password combination is not valid.

Comment: yes, but i am able to authenticate via command line using this credentials, but cannot from workbench

Comment: Probably your credentials are allowing only @localhost. Try using `@*`. Connections from outside WSL2 are not localhost

Comment: @EliasSoares Just tried to create new user and have same error and as well i cannot login with new user in WSL2, getting 
`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'andrew'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Comment: What host do those users have?

Comment: Newly created user has a start `*` in hosts column, another users has `localhost`

Comment: I don't `*` works there. Try `%`. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html#grant-accounts

Comment: yes, i already tried, i'm able to login with `WSL2` but same problem if i try from workbench

Comment: MySQL does not accept neither `andrew@localhost` nor `andrew@%` credentials? That's strange. Well, WLS2 is full of subtleties, I'm clueless at this point, sorry. In fact I thought you couldn't even run MySQL from WSL2. 

Comment: Just to clarify, i'm able to run it in the WSL with created credentials, but cannot connect from the `Windows` using `MySQL` workbench or via `IDE`